# Entire database is not exporting from phpmyadmin in Xampp

Tags: database, magento-1, export, localhost

The database is not exporting completely from phpmyadmin in my local server xampp.

Please tell me the way to export the entire database.

Comment: Please add some more information. Are some tables missing or the file cuts in some point. If so is it always in the same place or does it differ and sometimes you receive a little more.

Comment: Which operation system are you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the following lines at the bottom of `php.ini` file on my project

> ```
> max_input_vars = 5000
> suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
> suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
> ```

After added this, You must restart your Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command through terminal.

**mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p mydemo123 > mydatabase.sql**

- -h = Host Name
- -u = User Name
- mydemo123 = Database Name
- mydatabase.sql = Set file name with .sql extension

Comment: sorry can you please tell me how   to run this command

Comment: Run this command through terminal.